# Get Bootstrap datetimepicker to work after ajax loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have this simple script which works on a normal form:

```
<script>
        $(function () {
            $('.datepicker').datetimepicker({ pickTime: false, format: "DD-MM-YYYY" });
            $('.timepicker').datetimepicker({ pickDate: false, format: "HH:mm", pick12HourFormat: false });
        });

</script>
```

But if I load a form via ajax into a Bootstrap 3 modal - the time and date pickers dont work. I know the issue is because I am loading the form via ajax.

So how do I register the functions for the newly loaded ajax form?

Edit: this is how I am calling the ajax model:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-danger" href="/example" data-target="#myModal">Load Modal</a>
```

Comment: Can you post how you are loading the form?

Comment: @agentpx - I've editted my question

Comment: Place a jquery.js inside head tag of your modal example page. The parent page where you might have a reference to jquery is not visible to the second page which is you are showing as modal.

Comment: Cool - that actually works. Post as an answer and I'll accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place a jquery.js inside head tag of your modal example page. Jquery on the parent page where you might have referenced it is not visible to the second page which you are showing as modal.

Answer (score 6):

I have same issues, and this is my code

```
  $(document).on("focusin","input[type=date]", function () {
        $(this).datepicker({
            autoclose: true,
            format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
        });
    });
```

and note. add css

```
.datepicker{z-index:1151 !important;}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example code. Note how datetimepicker is called in success callback, after you've inserted form html

```
// this code gets called wheb whole page is loaded
$(function () {

  // this is your code to load form
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/path/to/form",
    data: data,

    // this is success callback, gets called when you got 
    // response from server
    success: function(response) {

      // here you take from html from response and insert it on the page
      $('#form_container').html(response);

      // and then you load bootstrap-datetimepicker
      $('.datepicker').datetimepicker({ pickTime: false, format: "DD-MM-YYYY" });
      $('.timepicker').datetimepicker({ pickDate: false, format: "HH:mm", pick12HourFormat: false });

    }
  });
});
```