# Bootstrap 3 datetimepicker doesn't trigger after container is get by ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I'm using bootstrap 3 datetimepicker component. I'm using construction:

```
$('.datetimepickerbutton').datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD.MM.YYYY'
});
```

And it's working fine, until I will send content by ajax. Ajax form is inside .myDate div and it's targer id. How should I use jquery's "on" method to has my code working for ajax also? Im' tried use:

```
$(".dataPoczatku").on("load", function () {
    $('.datetimepickerbutton').datetimepicker({
        format: 'DD.MM.YYYY'
    });
});
```

But now my datetime picker never is showing....

My question look like analogic to topic [Get Bootstrap datetimepicker to work after ajax loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27874336/get-bootstrap-datetimepicker-to-work-after-ajax-loaded) but all my stript links are in head and it didn't help in this case.

Comment: Can you show your ajax code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you initialize datepicker after ajax success. Like following instance:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body
}).done(function() {//success function now you can initialize datepicker
  $('.datetimepickerbutton').datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD.MM.YYYY'
  });
});
```

If your ajax call happening more then one times then you might have to use `$('.datetimepickerbutton').datetimepicker('remove');` before initialize. I suggest you to use `ID` instead of `Class`(*.datetimepickerbutton*), so that it will effect only specific element.

Comment: In my case there are some date boxes dynamically generated, so I can't use Id instead of Class. But implementation on success it resolved my issue, thank you very much for help.

Answer (score 0):

Another type of call:

```
var posting = $.post( url, data );
posting.done(function(output){
  $('#main-content').html(output).find('#datepicker').datepicker(datepickerOptions());
});

$('#main-content').load(this_file + ' #div' + this_id, {
  'id': this_id,
  'name': this_name
}, function(){
  $(this).find('#datepicker').datepicker(datepickerOptions())
});

function datepickerOptions() {
  var ToEndDate = new Date();
  return {
        todayBtn: true,
        orientation: "top left",
        autoclose: true,
        todayHighlight: true,
        endDate: ToEndDate,
      }
}
```

You can do the same with 'load', or any type of ajax call.

I had issues with showing datepicker: only on second click, showed, ie: when I got the focus. And this was working fine.

Thanks @Manwal for you solution, it helped me.